# Dynamic routing with multiple parameters in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next js. I want to use dynamic routing based on [this documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing). How can I set two parameters like href="/page/[p1]/[p2]" to the Link component? What should be the structure of my page file and how use the router.query?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used a wildcard and a query string like page/[p1]?p2=... , but I want use 2 wildcard.
Also use this structure for my page name [p1][p2].tsx

Comment: Check this https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing

Comment: Thanks, Its a good example

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with the help of dynamic routing in nextjs 9.
For example, `pages/post/[postId]/[commentId].js` would match `/post/p1/c1`. Its query object would be: { postId: 'p1', commentId: 'c1' }.
your Link component should be like this:

```
<Link
   href="/post/[postId]/[commentId]"
   as={`/post/${postId}/${commentId}`}>
      <a>link to comment</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: What would the file structure in the `pages` directory look like when doing this?

Comment: @P4nd4b0b3r1n0 
pages/post/[postId]/[commentId].js
you need a folder with the name of first parameter : [postId]
and the js file with the name of second one : [commentId].js

Comment: I was wondering if I should use both `[postId]` folder and `[postId].js` file if I wanted to handle both top-level and bottom-level pages, and indeed it works like that

Answer (score 34):

Folder structure should be Like that

```
Page - Folder 
 blog - Folder Name
 [p1] - Folder Name
   [p2].js - File Name
```

it will work when you call URL like /blog/postname/id it will call p2.js page

Comment: You can also get the details back in your [p2.js] file by 

    const {
    query: { p1, p2 },
  } = req;

console.log("P1="+p1);
console.log("P2="+p2);

Answer (score 3):

The folder structure in your nextjs projects should look like this

```
user
 ┗ [user-id]
   ┗  posts
      ┗ [post-id]
```

this will generate url paths for you like below, which is widely used format

```
/users/[id]/posts/[postId]
```

You can follow these guidelines to structure your urls: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/#h-nesting-resources-for-hierarchical-objects

In summary, formats like "/pages/p1/p2", do not really tell a whole lot of information what sub-resources you are choosing and are considered less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Folder structure like this will work

```
-[blog] //folder name
 -[post].js //file name
-items //folder name
 -[category] //folder name
  -[subCategory].js //file name
```

you can simply call the blog and post like

```
<a href="/blog/post"></a>
```

you can simply call the category and subcategory like

```
<a href="/items/category/subCategory"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other method is create a slug [...slug] and get the parameters with router.query.

***[dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)***

Comment: Igor Chaves, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)