# Next js - How to pass multiple parameters in url for api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, api, next.js

I am able to pass one parameter and get results from next js api

The docs are very helpful - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes

```
/api/posts/[postId].js
```

The above works but is there an option to pass another parameter like below?

```
/api/posts/[postId][userId].js
```

The folder name is currently [postId]. I tried renaming it to [postId][userId]

My code for api is

```
  let postVotes = await req.db.collection('votesPosts').count({"post":req.query.postId,"user":req.query.userId})
```

Comment: With `[postId][userId]` there is no separator, the system won't know how to map a url to that route.

Comment: Maybe a `[postId]/[userId]` could do it, and you would have a folder named `[userId]` with `index.js` or just a file named `[userId].js` where you would fetch the data as you did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic routing with multiple parameters in Next js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075798/dynamic-routing-with-multiple-parameters-in-next-js)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, routes don't handle multiple parameters in a single segment of the URL path. You can only have one parameter per segment:

```
/api/entity/{param1}/{param2}/sub/{param3}
```

Now in Next JS, you need to separate them too to have 2 segments with param:

```
/api/posts/[postId]/[userId]
```

Which would resolve to 2 possible files:

```
/api/posts/postId]/[userId]/index.js
```

if you do it with a parameter directory + index file, or

```
/api/posts/postId]/[userId].js
```

if you do it with a parameter file.

Doing it with directory + index file allow you to add fixed segments like:

```
/api/posts/postId]/[userId]/popular.js
/api/posts/postId]/[userId]/private.js
```

Then you can make your API call as you did it for 2 params.

Comment: Your answer makes sense so I have to see why my second level [userId]gives me 404 but level 1 works. May be next js wants [...slug] or [...params] but I have to play with this

Comment: Works fine with the nested folder structure. Thanks

Comment: I think spreading [...slug] is intended for infinite parameters like in javascript, but with multiple segments in the case of Next JS. I don't really use API Routes, but I use file system routing a lot in Next. Try playing with them to see