# Handle dynamic routes in Next Js and avoid collisions with other dynamic routes

Tags: next.js

I have a little problem with the routes in Next Js. One of the routes is for posts, but these have another variable and follows the next structure:

- /analysis/post-slug
- /opinion/post-slug
- /post/post-slug

So I tried using creting this route `pages/[postType]/[postSlug].js`. This is not working as I have another dynamic file `[policy].js` inside page folder:

```
|- [postType]
|  |- [postSlug].js
|    
|- index.js
|- login.js
|- [policy].js
|- _documents.js
```

The only way I have been able to solve this problem is to create one route per `[postType]`:

```
|- analysis
|  |- [postSlug].js
|- opinion
|  |- [postSlug].js
|- post
|  |- [postSlug].js
|    
|- index.js
|- login.js
|- [policy].js
|- _documents.js
```

The problem about this solution is that whenever I modify `[postSlug].js` I have to remember to update the others. Is there any way to solve this?

Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075798/dynamic-routing-with-multiple-parameters-in-next-js) but is not working for me.

Comment: You can't have 2 dynamic routes at the same level. Have you considered changing the `[policy]` route instead, since it doesn't have nested folders? Something like `policy/[id].js`. Another solution could be handling `[policy]` in `[postType]/index.js` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for yor response. It's finally what I did, but I wonder if there any way to avoid this problem.